# Display Matrix Report with two level grouping on a Visual Force Page

Tags: analytics, matrix

I want to display matrix report having two level row grouping and two level column grouping on a visualforce page using Reports Analytics API.
I have fetched the report metadata.
Want to display the metadata on a visualforce page in a structure similar to Matrix report.